# libgdx - not displayed actor added after the removal of another actor

Tags: scala, libgdx

I write a screen with two actors, i want replace one page to another after event. But after remove first page actor from the stage and add second page actor, i don't see neither the first nor the second page actor :(

```
class PageScreen extends Screen {

  def createPage(n:Int):Page = ...

  ...

  var stage:Stage = _
  var page:Page = _ // Page extends WidgetGroup
  var menu:Menu = _ // Menu extends WidgetGroup

  // mbassador subscribe to events
  bus.subscribe(this)

  @Handler
  def handleEvent(message: TailBookEvent): Unit = {
    message match {
      case ForwardPageButtonPressedEvent(_) =>
        stage.getActors.removeValue(page, true) // I tried everything
        stage.getRoot.removeActor(page) // I tried everything
        page = createPage(4)
        page.setDebug(true)
        stage.addActor(page) // I tried everything
        stage.getRoot.addActor(page) // I tried everything
        stage.getActors.add(page) // I tried everything
      ...
    }
  }

  override def show(): Unit = {
    stage=new Stage(new ScreenViewport())
    page = createPage(1)
    menu = new Menu(page.pageAtlas)
    stage.addActor(page)
    stage.addActor(menu)
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)
  }

  override def render(delta: Float): Unit = {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    if (stage != null) {
      stage.act(delta)
      stage.draw()
    }
  }

  override def resize(width: Int, height: Int): Unit = {
    if (stage != null) stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true)
    menu.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    page.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
  }

  override def dispose(): Unit = {
    if (stage != null) stage.dispose()
  }

  ...

}
```

even this code removes everything from the screen:

```
    stage.clear()
    page = createPage(page.pageNumber+1)
    page.setDebug(true)
    stage.addActor(page)
    stage.addActor(menu)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to perform these actions using `Gdx.app.postRunnable` method